# Oauth issue on production server, works on dev though

Tags: grails, oauth, facebook-oauth

Oauth for facebook works perfect on dev environment,

but it doesn't work on production server, callback URL is fine, it replies with this:

[http://mydomain.com/oauth/facebook/callback?code=AQDjyz5ckiXVl6yuOR_Xwg3eMUXcbTxeE8FjUA3UIwNj23Tgk1A2k1eaVCUARLituKh83u8JZY-giNrPb-_fFKOmIrJtB9wOA3szZaY84_pNG-UCOPSlcgpzllbu_-n80btCjZ4YQAx8BNaR-KmKuHgv3qhfga2JaOWppcAHqH9M_j4XGxbY9UGJYbVIKeMTm2Qtn1gl-ENGi9TR6Le4jS9Unpx_6ht0Jkk2bkCEvVk-VoQjHgpbAEFpqqD1Ds6shYi3TaKTC2EXc7ce6KKC3Z6FmCqAEOa93bo5YbcWns6xGrpZ2WtW72EB9xEkCzFXQVE#*=*](http://mydomain.com/oauth/facebook/callback?code=AQDjyz5ckiXVl6yuOR_Xwg3eMUXcbTxeE8FjUA3UIwNj23Tgk1A2k1eaVCUARLituKh83u8JZY-giNrPb-_fFKOmIrJtB9wOA3szZaY84_pNG-UCOPSlcgpzllbu_-n80btCjZ4YQAx8BNaR-KmKuHgv3qhfga2JaOWppcAHqH9M_j4XGxbY9UGJYbVIKeMTm2Qtn1gl-ENGi9TR6Le4jS9Unpx_6ht0Jkk2bkCEvVk-VoQjHgpbAEFpqqD1Ds6shYi3TaKTC2EXc7ce6KKC3Z6FmCqAEOa93bo5YbcWns6xGrpZ2WtW72EB9xEkCzFXQVE#_=_)

but then it does not show any page/error further. Its blank white page.
Its grails application.
Any suggestions?

Comment: How does the url look like before OAuth is called? Just wanted to see that the domain name matches with what is there in the callback url.

Comment: before OAuth its like 'http://mydomain.com', login is the popup on this page.